# Want to retrieve the table records by using condition of particular name of column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table name as Patient_Mst of the following is the actual schema design.

```
Patient_ID  bigint  
Patient_Investigator_ID varchar(100)    
Patient_Initial varchar(100)    
Patient_DOB varchar(50) 
Patient_DOJ varchar(50) 
SiteID  bigint  
Verified_By bigint  
Verified_Date   datetime    
Update_By   bigint  
Update_Date datetime    
Added_By    bigint  
Added_Date  datetime
```

I am using SQL Server, now what I need to do is to retrieve the data of the Patient_Mst where my Column_Name = 'Patient_DOB'

Like, I want to design a Query similiar to:

```
Select * from Patient_Mst where Column_Name = 'Patient_DOB'
```

Comment: Your query looks good to me.  Have you tried running it?

Comment: Yes I have Designed the Query like
Select * from PatientMst where sys.columns.name = 'Patient_DOB'

But unfortunately it give me error message like:
The multi-part identifier "sys.columns.name" could not be bound.

Comment: 'Patient_DOB' is a column name. what is your requirement exactly.

Comment: give the proper requirement. like what u want as result. sample data

Comment: @Sas yes it is a column name.

Comment: you cannot use sys.columns.name in ur table.

Comment: @Sas Yes. Agreed but do not know the other way to retrieve the data.

Comment: if you want to select the details of patient based on patient_dob the run

`select * from PatientMst where Patient_DOB ='specific_value_u_want'`

Comment: I guess you are looking for this Select * from Patient_Mst where Patient_DOB ='keywords'

Comment: No. I want to retrieve all the data of a table on the basis of column name provided in the where condition. 
The where condition does not pertain to a particular value. It is purely on the column name provided in the where clause.

Comment: Dhurvi u cannot put condition on column name. u can simple select the required column name in select statement

Answer (score 1):

If you just want that column, put it in the select statement:

```
SELECT Patient_DOB FROM Patient_Mst
```

The WHERE clause is used to filter out certain rows in the columns you select. For instance, if you only wanted records from this year, you could use WHERE in the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM Patient_Mst WHERE YEAR(Patient_DOB) = '2018'
```

This would return all the data where the patient year of birth is 2018.

Comment: You write 'If you just want that column, put it in the select statement'. The OP has clearly written 'Now what I need to do is to retrieve the data of the Patient_Mst where my Column_Name = 'Patient_DOB'

Comment: I mean, the question doesn't make a lot of sense.... I am trying to help the OP understand how to write a basic query.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Patient_Mst where [Patient_DOB] = [Patient_DOB]
```

Comment: This is the same as SELECT * FROM Patient_Mst

Comment: That may be but tell that to the OP, it is the query that satisfies the OP's need

Comment: By that logic, so does this query: SELECT * FROM Patient_Mst WHERE 'kbball' = 'kbball'

Comment: No dispute there but not what the OP is requesting